# how to find 16 most common colors in the img with extension BMP

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl

```
for(int yy=0; yy<height/2; yy++)
{
  SDL_Color kolor = getPixel(xx,yy); //we are gettig each pixel in img;

 setPixel(xx+width/2,yy+height/2,kolor.r,kolor.g,kolor.b );


 //setPixel(xx,yy+height/2,kolor.r,kolor.g,kolor.b);


 //setPixel(xx+width/2,yy,kolor.r,kolor.g,kolor.b);





}
```

}

I am trying by using a loop find 16 most common colors in an img and get its RGB.

I've been using mapping and trying to do something with structure but everything was in avail.

If you have some ideas about how to find these colors, I'll be sorely grateful. Thanks

Comment: Post the code you have written. Even though it wasn't working it will help us to understand exactly what you are trying to do, and will help us give a better answer because we'll see your abilities as a programmer. Without more information this question is going to get closed. The obvious missing piece of information is the format of the image and the way you extract colour information from it.

Comment: Are you reading 24bpp data or is it a palettised 8bpp image? If the former, are you looking for exact matches or are you allowing some tolerance?

Comment: If you allow some tolerance then this is the typical use for k-means algorithm. It gives you the "k" top colors and tell you which pixels are close to which color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a 4x4 img it would be simple.
Simplify likewise, histogram function each RGB level(0-255x3), expecting each "popular" color to be in there. Sort the mess into top 16 used for each, again expecting those to be correct. Unless you have wild color gyrations, nothing else.
Check second time to see if popular colors actually exist.
Last, you might want to group into "close enough" categories, jpegs are lossy to a fault, anything within 4 RGB variations is grouped together, reducing 0-256 values to 0-64, unless colors swing widely. If you've used paint program magic wand, you know tolerance=0 makes uber mistakes, same idea.
Median filter. It will definitely reduce color count by merging into an average messy color, sample a 3x3, 4x4, circular weighted sample area.

If all else fails, steal the 256 color safe web palette, and work from there.

SWAG-Scientific Wild Ass Guess method, good luck.